# How to send SMS using c#

Tags: c#, sms

i want to send sms using c# coding

Comment: Ok! And your question is... ?

Comment: I want a steak, medium rare, and a large beer

Comment: please send.... i've no problem

Answer (score 3):

Use SMSLib ( http://smslib.org/download/ )

You may find working codes here, i had worked using java platform, and it works all fine.
try for c#.

All you need is a gsm moden,connect to USB and provide proper port number in the availaible code at SMSlib website.

download http://smslib.org/download/files/smslib.net-v3.5.0.zip

You will find C# herein.

Answer (score 0):

I did both sms sending and receiving with the Api provided by https://www.csoft.co.uk/.
It is a paid service, but it is very easy to implement.

Answer (score -1):

download library from one of the sms sites and integrate:

[SMS provider](http://www.clickatell.com/)

It is very easy.

Comment: The website you provided is not available

Comment: This doesn't look like a library, it looks like a service you can subscribe to. Any APIs that are provided work only if you have a subscription to their service. Your answer really needs more explanation.

Comment: Of course you need to subscribe ! I don't know many providers that let you send SMS for free using API.

Comment: This is just one option, I use this provider, downloaded the library and hooked up sms in less than 5 min. you can use any other provider as well. considering the depth of the question, I think this answer was good enough directions..